# Sort strings in alphabetical order as they enter the array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, sorting

So I have a program that reads a file, adds the information into an array and then afterwards sorts the array using an exchange sort into alphabetical order. The problem is I misunderstood the assignment and need the strings to be sorted as they are entered into the array instead of using a separate sorting method after they are already entered. Heres what I have:

```
public class NumberCollection2
{
  String nextName;
  int nextNumber;
  private Person[] people = new Person[50];
  private int size =0; 

  public void load()
  {
    try
    {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(new File ("numbers.txt"));

      while (in.hasNextLine())
      {
        nextName = in.next();
        nextNumber = in.nextInt();
        people[size]=new Person(nextName, nextNumber);
        size++;
        in.nextLine();

      }

      //use exchange sort to sort in ascending alphabetical order
      int i, j;

      for ( i = 0;  i < size - 1;  i++ )
      {
        for ( j = i + 1;  j < size;  j++ )
        {  
          if ( people[ i ].getName().compareTo(people[ j ].getName()) > 0 )
          {                                            
            Person temp = people [ i ];
            people [ i ] = people [ j ];    
            people [ j ] = temp; 

          } 
        } 

      }

    }
```

This works perfectly yet my professor needs it to be sorted as it is entered into the array "people" and I am not sure how to approach that. Any advice/help would be awesome, thanks!!!

this is the email I got from my prof : "To receive full credit, you must insert each item into its sorted position in the array as it is read in. It is not ok to read it all in and call a sort routine."

Comment: Instead of comparing with two four loops, with one element against another, consider replacing one of the loops with user-input.

Answer (score 0):

"my professor needs it to be sorted as it is entered"

This is a linked list, not an array.

So, you can only view the current item in stack/queue (FILO/FIFO).

You're professor probably means to print the list the way it was entered.

You can do this by creating the list as a queue.
Java has a call you can use, called `Queue`.  There is also `Stack` and `LinkedList`.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense but this is the email I got from my prof : "To receive full credit, you must insert each item into its sorted position in the array as it is read in. It is not ok to read it all in and call a sort routine." So I am using an array